# How do I bind "Enter" to a command in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I went to Code->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts to bind ENTER to the `acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter` command (somehow my VS Code stopped letting me accept input suggestion by pressing Enter...), but I wasn't able to enter ENTER by pressing it when it asked me to "*press desired key combination and then press ENTER*" because the entry box closes on ENTER.

vs code version: 1.72.2
On a Mac

Comment: Hi & welcome! It seems impossible "with dialog", but you *can create* <kbd>Enter</kbd> keybinding (..in `keybindings.json`).. like shown [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_command-arguments)

Comment: I'm baffled how this horrible UI was approved and currently is in actual VS Code

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult (impossible?) to do in the keyboard shortcuts UI for the reason you mentioned, but you can do it in the keybindings.json file with `"key": "enter"` like shown [in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_command-arguments). You can open up keybindings.json using the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).